# Does authenticating against oauth2/token endpoint count towards API Request Limits?

Tags: rest-api, governorlimits, oauth2, authentication, limits

Does authenticating against the Salesforce OAuth2 token endpoint count towards API Request Limits?

```
Instance URL + /services/oauth2/token
```

Comment: You can check with limits rest api `/services/data/v49.0/limits`

Comment: @NagendraSingh - does checking `/services/data/v49.0/limits` count against your limits? :-)

Comment: Yes even that does. Each time we hit that the daily limits decreases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this counts both as an API call for purposes of daily limits, and a login/hour limit (3,600 login calls per hour).